# How to apply a function to a column of data and produce comment in adjacent column based on specific argument in R

Tags: r

I want a function that will go through a column of data from top to bottom and where the number starts to increase above 5, it should produce text in an adjacent comment column saying "Grade in". Then when then number decreases below 5 I want it to say "Grade out", how do I do this?

Not sure where to start with this but want it to look like this:

| Average load | Comment |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Grade in |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 0 | Grade out |

Comment: With your example, did you want "Grade in" to be in the same row with average load = 0 since the following row is 5 or above? Or should it be in the following row?

Comment: Hi Ben, yes I wanted it to be in the same row as average load= 0

Comment: Hi Ben thank you, almost. rather than creating a column called comment I want it to write grade in grade out in an existing column called comment.

Comment: See edited answer. Just change the default in the `case_when` to `comment` and it will keep whatever is in the `comment` column unless there is a change above/below 5 in average load, in which case it will overwrite what's there. Let me know if this is what you had in mind.

Comment: That's brilliant thank you, it worked. I posted another similar problem you may be able to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to detect transitions above and below 5 for average load. If so, you can use a `case_when` statement for this two situations, using `lag` previous row and `lead` following row as reference.

```
df <- data.frame(
  average_load = c(0, 5, 6, 0),
  comment = ""
)

library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(comment  = case_when(
    average_load < 5 & lead(average_load, default = first(average_load)) >= 5 ~ "grade in",
    average_load < 5 & lag(average_load, default = first(average_load)) >= 5 ~ "grade out",
    .default = comment
  ))
```

**Output**

```
  average_load   comment
1            0  grade in
2            5          
3            6          
4            0 grade out
```